# Pop up book effect with CSS animations

Tags: html, css, animation, popup

So I want to make a pop-up book effect but in 2D only. (so NOT like the [beercamp](http://2012.beercamp.com/) page).

Ideal results:

- bottom of img stays in the same position
- img starts invisible then is popped up (imagine it lying on its back, then being lifted up till it is vertical)
- Item should not appear too (if possible) compressed

I've read into CSS animations, the closest animation I can find is

```
transform: rotateX(xdeg);
```

So I produced this to test it out:

```
<!doctype html>

<style type="text/css">

#popup
{
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: popupanim;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes popupanim
{
    from {
        transform: rotateX(90deg);
    }

    to {
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
}
</style>

<body>
    <img id="popup" src="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif" width=379px height=400px/>
</body>
```

The problem with this is that the bottom level of the image changes, and that the image is obviously compressed.
How could I improve this to meet my needs?

(also as a side not rotate3d(xdeg, ydeg, zdeg) does not produce any output, why?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a container element and use the `transform-origin` property to make it pivot properly:

```
#container {
    display: inline-block;

    perspective: 600px;  /* Tweak this */
}

#popup {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    transform-origin: bottom;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BEy9f/3/**

You need to use a parent element (`#container`) to make the perspective work properly. Also, if the `#popup` isn't in the exact center of the element (which is why I put `display: inline-block` in there), it'll appear off-center in the animation.

Chrome supports 3D transformations as well, so you can add support by using the `-webkit-` prefix.

Comment: Worked almost perfectly - do I _need_ to have the perspective? To have a flat object in the first place, I remove the perspective (perspective:0px;).

Comment: Oh, and if I replace transform with -webkit-transform, do I need to include the original 'transform:' for function on other browsers, or can it entirely be replaced by '-webkit-transform:'

Comment: @louisdeb: Yes, `-webkit-` properties only work on Webkit browsers.